# Updating cell in Pandas based on previous cell and different Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, math

Im trying to calculate a value of a cell at position L based on other data in the DataFrame I have and I cant figure out what the nomeclature would be. Its even kind of complicated to type out, but its a fairly standard implementation in excel. I've shown an example below, I'm asking about the Logic of Col2 in this instance. Please forgive the poor formatting.

|         Col1        |        Col2      |

|          X          |         A        |

|          Y          |        Y+A       |

|          Z          |       Z+Y+A      |

Comment: Could you explain in more details what you are trying to do? It seems unclear from your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to your Title question.

Suppose your df is:

```
    col1
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   4
4   5
```

you want to add A in the logic you have given.

```
A = 5
(df['col1']).cumsum().add(A) - df['col1'][0]
```

---

**Output:** <-- this will give you column two values

```
0     5
1     7
2    10
3    14
4    19
Name: col1, dtype: int64
```

---

```
df['col1']).cumsum()
```

will give:

```
1 (1)
3 (1+2)
6 (1+2+3)
10 (1+2+3+4)
15 (1+2+3+4+5)
```

---

adding A=5 will give:

```
6 (1+5)
8 (1+2+5)
11 (1+2+3+5)
15 (1+2+3+4+5)
20 (1+2+3+4+5+5)
```

---

subtracting the 1st value will give you:

```
5 (1+5-1)
7 (1+2+5-1)
10 (1+2+3+5-1)
14 (1+2+3+4+5-1)
19 (1+2+3+4+5+5-1)
```

equivalent to

```
5 (5) <-- A
7 (2+5) <-- Y + A
10 (2+3+5) <-- Z + Y + A
14 (2+3+4+5) 
19 (2+3+4+5+5)
```

Comment: Where did you learn about the cum() command? 

Also, this was a very helpful explanation.

Comment: I learned it by solving some of the questions and obviously learned from jezrael's answer on pandas. Is your question resolved? If yes can you close it by accepting the answer. If it's the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a forloop, the cumsum did not do everything I needed. I'll post the code snippit below incase anyone needs it.

```
for x in range(len(pDiff['HP Change'])) : 
    if x == 0:                            #special rules for first cell
        pDiff.iat[x, 2] = HPStateInit
        pDiff.iat[x, 2] = 4
    else:
        pDiff.iat[x, 2] = pDiff.iat[x, 1] + pDiff.iat[x-1,2]                   
                                          #Boundary Condition implementation
    pDiff['HP State'].loc[(pDiff['HP State'] > 7)] = 7                                                    
    pDiff['HP State'].loc[(pDiff['HP State'] < 0)] = 0
```